# WSO2 ESB : how to retrive the Carbon Applications List

Tags: wso2, monitoring, jmx, snmp, wso2-esb

for monitoring purpose I was looking for a way, possibly via JMX or SNMP, to retrieve the Carbon Applications List and for each one of those the version.
I googled and read the docs but wasn't able to find anything
Any idea ?

TIA

Max

Comment: The deployed .car files are located in this folder: \repository\deployment\server\carbonapps  Perhaps this will help? The version, is part of their name, by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the list or carbon apps deployed by calling admin services.

To get the list of carbon apps you should invoke ApplicationAdmin admin service.

Admin Service URL: https://localhost:9443/services/ApplicationAdmin

Sample Request Payload:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mgt="http://mgt.application.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mgt:listAllApplications/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Sample Response Payload:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:listAllApplicationsResponse xmlns:ns="http://mgt.application.carbon.wso2.org" xmlns:ax21="http://mgt.application.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
         <ns:return>ContainerAPICompositeApplication_1.0.0</ns:return>
         <ns:return>SalesforceCompositeProject_1.0.0</ns:return>
      </ns:listAllApplicationsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Make sure you pass in the authenticated session ID when making the request. You can find more details on this at : http://itsmaheeka.blogspot.com/2016/06/wso2-admin-services.html

Comment: you are a star! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: seems like I have some issue 
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

< Connection: close
< Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
<
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode><faultstring>com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "aut"
* Closing connection #0
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,165]</faultstring><detail/></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: try with this request : <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://authentication.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <aut:login>
         <aut:username>admin</aut:username>
         <aut:password>admin</aut:password>
         <aut:remoteAddress>localhost</aut:remoteAddress>
      </aut:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: No :(

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</wsa:Action></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:VersionMismatch</faultcode><faultstring>Only SOAP 1.1 or SOAP 1.2 messages are supported in the system</faultstring><detail/></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope

Comment: Can you share your request payload and the request here?

Comment: ok this one works for me (after the authentication and grab the JSessionID
`code` <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mgt="http://mgt.application.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mgt:listAllApplications/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>